# Connect to HANA database from docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hana, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I need to connect to SAP HANA database from docker container.
It's asp net core web api project

I added those lines to my dockerfile:

```
# Create hdbclient directory and copy hdbclient folder to the container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/sap/hdbclient
COPY ../hdbclient /usr/sap/hdbclient

# Set HDBDOTNETCORE environment variable
ENV HDBDOTNETCORE /usr/sap/hdbclient/dotnetcore
```

without those lines it does not work when running on debug, but with those lines everything is okay.
Probelem is that after publishing docker image hana connection does not work, there is no exception or anything execution just stops at this:

```
HanaConnection conn = new(connectionString);
```

and hangs there no errors no messages nothing.

What can it be? how can I even try to investigate it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue running SapHana client connector for dotnet core 6 in linux container.

I have downloaded the Sap.Data.Hana.Core.v2.1.dll and libadonetHDB.so from SAP official link: https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools

What I noticed in my cluster is that the first time the application start for around 5/10 minutes the job is employed to do some stuff when you invoke:

```cs
using (HanaConnection hanaConnection = new HanaConnection(connectionString))
{ ... }
```

I attach an image for demonstrating that CPU/Memory is busy in that period.
After the first initialization, the connector will reply in some seconds without this issue.

[image]

If I use the libadonetHDB.dylib on my macOs this issue is not replicable.

Seems to be an issue with the Linux library...

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.sln .
COPY MySolutionApi.Data/*.csproj ./MySolutionApi.Data/
COPY MySolutionApi.Services/*.csproj ./MySolutionApi.Services/
COPY MySolutionApi.WebApi/*.csproj ./MySolutionApi.WebApi/
COPY nuget.config .
COPY ["Sap.Data.Hana.Core.v2.1.dll", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore

# copy full solution over
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build

# publish the API
FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /app/MySolutionApi.WebApi
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/MySolutionApi.WebApi/out ./
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "MySolutionApi.WebApi.dll" ]
```

I inserted for simplicity my Sap.Data.Hana.Core dll inside the solution for building purpose.
Then path for the linux libadonetHDB.so library is referenced as environment variable as following HDBDOTNETCORE = "/app/saplibs" where /app/saplibs is my volume mounted in my cluster.

Hope this will help.

Dave.

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for your support!

I followed your insructions to download latest version of library but still issue remains...
When I start container CPU (100%) and Memory are allocted quite lot but no  matter how long...

Comment: Can you share your DOCKERFILE?

Comment: Hi @DEPARTED I have updated my post. Have a look on that if could help you.

Comment: @DEPARTED ensure that your process is not killed because you do not have enough memory in the startup phase. I saw that with 8Gb of ram you are quite safe.

Comment: Hi David,

I checked there is at least 15GB memory available for this container and it's using it fully.

Comment: About your DOCKERFILE, so you did'nt copy entire folder of hdbclient as I did? 
Maybe that's causing this issue with my container?

Comment: @DEPARTED could you try to copy only the .dll in your container in order to build your project and then link the volume with only the .so file used by HANA.

Comment: Hi David, can I do this if my docker host machine is Windows?

Comment: Yes sure, docker container run linux os so yes you can share a folder with Linux .so library

Comment: Hi @DEPARTED I solve this issue just a day ago. You need to put the .dll for the correct OS and the library (for linux the libadonetHDB.so) in the /app folder together with the other dlls in the last stage (the runtime one) without mounting volumes and without defininig env variables. Sap code will look in that directory ;)

Comment: Hey, I just tried it and worked! 

Thanks a lot David.